# Show only those pages that are created by the specific logged in user in WordPress

Tags: plugins, pages, wp-admin, user-roles

In WordPress, I created a new User role called "Customers" to only see the pages in the wp-admin Dashboard that only that role has created and not all the pages that are created by other Customers or the Administrator. I mean every Customer would see their own created pages only. I have installed Adminimize, Ultimate Member, PublishPress Permissions, and User Role Editor plugins. But I couldn't do it. Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please do not post the same question in multiple sites. Originally posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76666381/show-only-those-pages-that-are-created-by-the-specific-logged-in-user-in-wordpre

Comment: Apology. I have deleted the question from stackoverflow and it will reside here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to an [mu-plugin](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/must-use-plugins/) (custom user role is `so76666381`) (tested):

```php
// Adjust admin queries to only show pages by current user if has custom role.
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', static function ( $query ) {

    // Limit hiding pages only to admin queries.
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get post types from query.
    $post_types = ( array ) $query->get( 'post_type', array() );

    // If pages are not being queried, bail.
    if ( ! in_array( 'page', $post_types ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get user's current role(s).
    $roles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;

    // If user does not have custom role, bail.
    if ( ! is_array( $roles ) || ! in_array( 'so76666381', $roles ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Limit results to those by current user with custom role.
    $query->set( 'author', get_current_user_id() );
} );
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. This worked. But now the problem is that when a new "Customer" registers him/ herself, they see all the pages until and unless they create one of their own. Once they add a new page, then they see only that page and the others don't appear then.

Comment: Sir, I modified this line as: `if ( ! is_array( $roles ) || ( ! in_array( 'customers', $roles ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) ) {
        return;
    }`

and its working perfectly. Thanks a ton!